# SignalR reconnect to other url

Tags: signalr

I need connect to other port after disconnect

Sample:

1. connected to zxy.com:8080/signalr
2. disconnect
3. connected to zxy.com:8081/signalr
4. disconnect
5. connected to zxy.com:8082/signalr

Now I work that

```js
function SignalR(port) {
    var conn = $.hubConnection(root + ':' + port + '/signalr', { useDefaultPath: false });
    manager.hub = conn.createHubProxy('myHub');
    conn.stateChanged(state => {
        case $.signalR.connectionState.disconnected:
            manager.hub.connection.stop();
            setTimeout(function () {
                    port++;
                    SignalR(port);
                }, 5000);
                break;
    })
```

It work but i want use default/easy code

```js
function SignalR(port) {
  //SET CORRECT port
  manager.hub = $.connection.myHub;
  $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
  });
  $.connection.hub.disconnected(function () {
        //DISPOSE CURRENT
        setTimeout(function () {
            port++;
            SignalR(port);
        }, 5000);
    });
```

I don't want rewrite all code to

```js
manager.hub.client.someEvent(...)
to
manager.hub.on('someEvent', ...)

manager.hub.server.someMethod();
to
manager.hub.invoke('someMethod', ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$.connection.hub.url = host + port + '/signalr';
$.connection.hub.start();
```